# Будет ли кошерно использовать сервлет как Rest-сервис, принимающий и генерирующий json

Tags: java-ee, веб-программирование, веб-служба, сервлеты

В чем вообще разница сервлета и сервиса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сервлет - это конкретное понятие из спецификации Servlet API - класс выполняющий некоторую работу - со своим жизненным циклом, иерархией классов и инфраструктурой. Обычно говорят конкретно об HTTP-сервлетах, в таком случае это любой класс, дочерний от [javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html). Вы определяете в нем реакцию на конкретные HTTP-запросы (GET, POST и т.п.). После этого он может быть развернут по определенному URL в сервлет-контейнере (Tomcat, Jetty).

Сервис - это широкое понятие: некий интерфейс, доступный извне, к которому можно обратиться (как правило, из другого процесса или с другого хоста) с целью выполнить что-то и, опционально, получить результат.

Очевидно, что сервис может быть реализован сервлетом, но не обязательно только им. Сервис может быть доступен, например, через RMI, Thrift, HTTP-сервер без участия сервлетов.

---

Что касается вопроса из заголовка: да, кошерно. Но с оговоркой. Нет смысла вручную писать велосипеды по сериализации/десериализации JSON, ручной работе с потоками ввода-вывода и заголовками, когда есть спецификация JAX-RS и ее реализации: CXF, RESTEasy, Jersey. JAX-RS позволяет сосредоточиться на решаемой задаче и писать код вида:

```java
@Path("/some/path)
public class MyRestService {

    @GET
    public Foo getMyFoo() {
        // ваша бизнес-логика 
    }
}
```